# disable Compress old files checking in Disk Cleanup in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, compression, disk-cleanup

On an OS drive with approx 168K files, 27K folders of approx 28GB, that include OS (Windows XP SP3), drivers and a bunch of large applications such as Visual Studio, MS Sql Server, MySql, Java, Microsoft Office and many others (no user content such as images, documents, database etc. not even in My Documents, Desktop, I save all my data on other drives), the *Calculating how much space...* in Disk Cleanup process takes 15 to 18 minutes to gather information of which 12 to 15 minutes are taken just by "Compress old files" calculation.

I don't want to use this feature. Is there any option, registry modification, policy setting etc. or any third party software tool by which I can **disable Compress old files calculation checking** on Disk Cleanup. I use Disk Cleanup on a regular basis so if this option can be disabled / removed from the process it is likely to save a lot of time.

**EDIT**
Please DO NOT suggest *How I can enable or disable compression*. I want to know if this option can be removed from Disk Cleanup i.e. **SKIP compression space calculation step** when the cleanup utility is checking how much space is ... (which takes about 12-15 minutes)

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/61925/windows-disk-cleanup-compress-old-files-option?rq=1) question applies to you

Comment: @Ramhound Don't you think that before suggesting anything you should read the question properly and understand what the OP is asking for?

Comment: I read the question, I read the duplicate, and I concluded they are the same.  **If you uncheck the option then Windows won't perform that step**  Your accepted answer basically does what disabling the option does by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound To be more clear I updated the question, so that any other user searching for same option could benefit. However, Mark's suggested answer did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Compress old files

Rename or delete it.